# IIS6 - Classic ASP - "out of memory"/"out of string space"

Tags: iis, iis-6, performance-tuning, memory-usage, application-pools

We have a classic ASP application that's under significantly more load than usual.

We are from time to time been getting "out of memory" and "out of string space" in the httperr. We do not usually see these errors.

For the moment we cannot change the application.

Is there anything we can do to the IIS config which will help to reduce or stop these errors occurring ?

The application pool is set to default values currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not changing the application mean not looking into why the load has increased or what pages are leading to this error?

Based on what you've stated in your question, that's the place I'd start with.

Otherwise, you've said application pool - I only support Classic ASP code, but can you increase the app pool recycling?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93932/out-of-string-space-in-visual-basic-6 which I'd say backs-up my suggestion of looking into what pages are causing the issues, now that the application is under load. If there's a programming issue, you'll keep running into it until it's fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We do know both the page that is causing the problem and why the load has gone up (basically 5x as many users were asked to use the application temporarily). However internal controls on change mean that altering the application is not feasible within 48 hours.

Comment: Would you suggest just recycling every x minutes or get involved in setting memory limits ?

Comment: Having now read the stackoverflow question you linked to - yes it is a string concatentaion which was never optimal but which was 'OK' in the context of the original user base - it seems it's now causing problems.

Comment: Honestly, I'd either set up some performance checks or do it manually and see what CPU/memory is looking like. If you can bump up the memory you could start there, but the one time we had to do a quick fix we ended up having the app pool recycle much more frequently. If you're using defaults, IIRC that's a little over a day. So you could look at x hours, or if it's coming in at certain times, switch it to recycle during/after those periods of time.

Comment: Of course, keep in mind the particular needs of your site; if recycling is going to result in, say, lost session information, then work your way down, instead of just going with a small value. Assuming your situation allows for it (versus you just need to get it resolved asap and can't spend time testing).